# D3 day/hour heatmap - nesting data issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a day/hour heatmap as in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084.

I am trying to create a dataset similar to the one in the example, which looks like this:

```
day hour    value
1   1   16 
1   2   20
1   3   0
...
```

I did this by first using d3.histogram to bin my data by hour, and I then use d3.nest to nest it by day of the week and hour:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
                        .key(function(d) { return formatTimeDay(new Date(d.x0)); })
                        .key(function(d) { return  formatTimeHour(new Date(d.x0)); })
                        .rollup(function(v) { return d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.length; }); })
                        .object(bins);
```

Which gives me a dataset showing - day: {hour: value, hour2: ...}:

```
1: {"00": 0.4, "01": 1.4, ..
2: {"00": 0.2, "01": 4.3..
```

Now I need to draw the rectangles, which in the example is done like this:

```
  var cards = svg.selectAll(".hour")
          .data(data, function(d) {return d.day+':'+d.hour;});

      cards.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("rx", 4)
          .attr("ry", 4)
          .attr("class", "hour bordered")
          .attr("width", gridSize)
          .attr("height", gridSize)
          .style("fill", colors[0]);
```

But I can't figure out how to do this using the nested data, or how to restructure it so that it looks like the data in the example.

Comment: Could you post your full code and a sample of your input data here so users can see what you have tried so far? A link to a jsfiddle / .block with the full dataset would be helpful, too. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var flatList = [];

for (var day in nested_data) {
    var day_data = nested_data[day];
    for (var hour in day_data) {
        flatList.push( { day: +day, hour: +hour, value: day_data[hour]} );
    }
}
```